# Export pictures from Excel (2016) file into gif using VBA ends up with Blank Screen

Tags: excel, vba, export

We have an Excel file called "Calendar", basically a file where we arrange shifts for workers. We used to export today's and the next days shift into a gif file and and reflect it to dashboards. Well VBA code was working until we migrated to Excel 2016. Code still executes without error however, when I check gif file, I just see a blank screen with no data.

Below you can find the source code:

```
Sub ExportGIF()
Dim cht As Chart

Worksheets("today").Activate

With Range("A1:CC13")

.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, .Height).Chart
End With
cht.Paste
cht.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
On Error Resume Next
Kill "DBStoday.gif"
On Error GoTo 0
'cht.Export "DBStoday.gif", "gif"
cht.Export "Q:\DBStoday.gif", "gif"
cht.Parent.Delete


With Range("A14:CC26")

.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, .Height).Chart
End With
cht.Paste
cht.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
On Error Resume Next
Kill "DBSnext.gif"
On Error GoTo 0
'cht.Export "DBStoday.gif", "gif"
cht.Export "Q:\DBSnext.gif", "gif"
cht.Parent.Delete


Worksheets("Calendar").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing once for my Company. 
However i declared `cht` as `ChartObject`.

I modified a part of your code so it looks more like how i did it, which works on Excel 2016.

Maybe try this approach:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject

Worksheets("today").Activate

With Range("A1:CC13")
    .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, .Height)
End With    

with cht
    .Activate
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    .Chart.Export Filename:="Q:\DBStoday.gif", Filtername:="gif"
    .Delete
end with
```

Oh and you don't need to kill the file first. it will be overwritten by the newly exported Version.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @horst I followed your advice and finally VBA works just as expected , here the final working code below

```
Sub ExportGIF()
Dim cht As ChartObject

Worksheets("today").Activate

With Range("A1:CC13")
    .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, .Height)
End With

With cht
    .Activate
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    .Chart.Export Filename:="Q:\DBStoday.gif", Filtername:="gif"
    .Delete
End With

Worksheets("today").Activate

With Range("A14:CC26")
    .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, .Width, .Height)
End With

With cht
    .Activate
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = 0
    .Chart.Export Filename:="Q:\DBSnext.gif", Filtername:="gif"
    .Delete
End With


End Sub
```